# Is there a good way to store logging calls for publishing as log messages later?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I often find myself stuck in the early phases of a program wanting to write log messages before logging has been configured.  This might happen if the log configuration itself is being loaded from some remote location or even logging about steps in logging setup.

Two options have come to mind but I'm not sure about either:

#### Option: Save the calls but not actually invoke logging.

It might be possible to capture some of the logging by using a sort of dummy logger that simply stores a list of `functools.partial` bindings to actual logger methods.  When logging is ready the dummy logger can then rerun all the calls direct into the intended logger.

The problem with this approach is that some aspects of logging are dependent on the call stack.  Standard `logging.basicConfig()` then `exc_info=True` will need to be converted into `exc_info=sys.exc_info()`.

If other, more exotic handlers have been configured such as [structlog](https://pypi.org/project/structlog/) they may try to extract more information out of the call stack than I'm aware.

#### Option: Add a special handler and re-run the logs

In theory this might work, but I'm not sure about rerunning information through a logger that was otherwise saved in a log hander.  I don't know what translation was otherwise saved.  It feels like there is much more scope with this solution to scramble messages.

As far as I know, log handlers receive subtly different information to the parameters passed to a logger.  I don't feel confident I could reverse that translation ready for reingesting.

Yet if I don't reingest the messages, how would I leverage the configuration of loglevels, filtering, etc. when the logging has been configured and the messages ready to publish.

---

Just to clarify what I need to do.  I need to write log messages before `logging` has been configured.  At the point these log messages are written, I don't even know what my future configuration will be.

Then I configure `logging` and I have a bunch of saved log messages that I want to write out.  I want to write them as if they were written with `logging` fully configured.

My assumption is the right way to do this is to ask `logging` to do this for me at the once it is configured.

---

Am I missing something?  Is there a good way to hold back python logging messages until logging has been fully configured?

Comment: Re, your comment, I don't know what you mean by "re-running" / "re-ingesting". If you buffer the records as I suggest, you can output them anyhow you want at a later date ,.. use e.g. a file, console or other handler and do `handler.handle(record)` based on any criteria you want. The records contain all the info you passed into the original logging call, and you can apply any filtering rules etc. you need. The logging docs are fairly clear on how the flow of info between loggers and handlers works. Read the docs on `logging.LogRecord`.

Comment: In what context do you need to write log messages before logging is configured? What stops you from loading the configuration (from anywhere) before you actually start logging stuff?

Comment: @chepner Why would I NOT want the option of having log entries generated by dependencies prior to configuring logging? Picking a json file from disk or environment variable might have no meaningful logs, but almost any remote location or complex parsing is going to issue log entries. Whether I'm using SQLAlchemy or Boto3 to pull the configuration from somewhere, they will begin logging before I know what the configuration is. If the process of finding and fetching configuration is complex enough then informative messages about _which_ configuration is being used might also be usful.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a custom handler based on `logging.handlers.BufferingHandler` (abstract class) or `logging.handlers.MemoryHandler` for this. They store logged events in a buffer that you can process later according to your needs.

Comment: Having worked a way down through this as a solution, I can see that I might be able to write saved log messages with [handle()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.handle). Sadly processing log messages through to a handler risks dropping important log messages. `sqlalchemy` and others will change their own log level on import.  So sqlalchemy messages would not make it into `BufferingHandler` even if subsequent log configuration changed that level. If I temporarily reset the `sqlalchemy` then it'll be hard to restore after applying log configuration.